# Redirect According To Device

Tags: node.js, express

In Node I am trying to send response according to device. If it is Web I am sending one kind of respone and If it is Mobile I am sending another kind of response. But I don't know how to find the device and implement condition.

**TS**

```
if(mobile){                                    //How to check whether it is mobile
res.send(res.mobile)
}
else if(web){                                  //How to check whether it is web
res.send(res.web)
}
else{
res.send(res.error)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `npm install node-device-detector --production`

```js
const DeviceDetector = require('node-device-detector');
const DeviceHelper = require('node-device-detector/helpers');

const detector = new DeviceDetector;
const userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0; NX505J Build/KVT49L) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.78 Mobile Safari/537.36';
const result = detector.detect(userAgent);

/* check device type (feature phone, smartphone or phablet) */
DeviceHelper.isMobile(result);
/* check device type is desktop */
DeviceHelper.isDesktop(result);
/* check device type is tablet  */
DeviceHelper.isTabled(result);
/* check device type car (side panel in car)  */
DeviceHelper.isCar(result);
/* check device type feature phone (push-button telephones)  */
DeviceHelper.isFeaturePhone(result);
/* check device type smartphone  */
DeviceHelper.isSmartphone(result);
/* check device type phablet  */
DeviceHelper.isPhablet(result);
/* check device type game console (xBox, PlayStation, Nintendo etc)  */
DeviceHelper.isConsole(result);
/* check device type smart speaker (Alisa, Alexa, HomePod etc) */
DeviceHelper.isSmartSpeaker(result);
/* check device type SmartTV/TV box */
DeviceHelper.isTv(result);
/* check device type portable camera */
DeviceHelper.isCamera(result);
/* portable terminal, portable projector */
DeviceHelper.isPeripheral(result);
/*  */
DeviceHelper.isSmartDisplay(result);
/* check device type boxes, blu-ray players */
DeviceHelper.isPortableMediaPlayer(result);
/* check device type watches, headsets */
DeviceHelper.isWearable(result);
```

Replace userAgent with your Header : req.headers['user-agent'].

More example https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-device-detector

Comment: will it support node v8

Comment: Yes it will support !